# Unable to share data between Components in Angular using service

Tags: angular

I have a login page, where, for the moment, I just have a button that changes the value of the message to be shared between my 'login' page and my 'home' page
However, the updated value of the message is seen only in login component's html as the {{message}}

login.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from '../data.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  message: string;
  constructor(public dataService: DataService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.dataService.currentMessage.subscribe(message => this.message = message)
  }

  newMessage() {
    console.log(this.message);
    this.dataService.changeMessage("new message");
    //this.dataService.username = "changed";
    console.log(this.message);
  }
}
```

data.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService {
  //username: string;
  private messageSource = new BehaviorSubject<string>("default message");
  currentMessage = this.messageSource.asObservable();

  constructor() { 
  //  this.username="original" 
  }

  changeMessage(message: string) {
    this.messageSource.next(message)
  }

}
```

and home.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from '../data.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  message: string;
  constructor(public dataService: DataService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.dataService.currentMessage.subscribe(message => this.message = message)
  }

}
```

Why is the {{message}} in my home page staying the same as "default message" when it is changing in the login page on clicking on the button? Please help!

Comment: Nevermind. I was typing the endpoints instead of navigating to the with the help of a button. My bad.

Comment: it should work fine.